# Best way to read next non-blank character from file in C

Tags: c, file-io

What is the best (shortest) way to read the next non-blank (not space/newline/tab) character from a file in a C program?

I realize I could probably use gets followed by strtok, but it seems like there has to be something more concise.

If so, let me know; if not, let me know that too.

Thanks.

Comment: Never use `gets`. Burn whatever book you learned it from. :-)

Comment: Ha ha.  I'd love to but I heard about from the internets and I don't know of any way to burn those down. :-)

Comment: indeed, flaming only seem to make it stronger.

Comment: I heard dragging The Internet into the Recycle Bin works if you're on AOL.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
char c;
fscanf(f, " %c", &c);
```

OR

```
int c;
while (isspace(c=fgetc(f)));
```

Comment: Interesting, I didn't realize scanf would behave that way with a space in it.  Looks like they have it documented in the "Whitespace character" section here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/scanf/ . Thanks for the answer.

Comment: That site is not a good source for information about the C library. For instance it says `scanf` returns the number of fields read; this is wrong. `scanf` returns the number of fields converted and stored, which will be fewer if you use the `*` modifier to suppress storage. It gets a lot of the corner cases wrong; you'd be better off getting the C standard (http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) for authoritative documentation.

Comment: Ahh yeah going to the original source.  That's smart :-)  Thanks. Just for you I'm going to print off some pages from that website and burn them the next time I'm around fire.

Comment: @R..GitHubSTOPHELPINGICE Thanks for `" %c"`. Is there a similar concise way to read any char but not newline char (`\n`)? We can skip over it or leave it in the stream i.e. not consuming it.

Comment: @rootkea: Maybe `"%1[^\n]"` or similar.

Comment: @R..GitHubSTOPHELPINGICE That will try to write `\0` in unauthorized memory since we have declared a `char`. Maybe there is no simple way. Either it has to be string (`"%1[^\n]"`) or we gotta check input char for `\n` and then "`ungetc`; done" or `getc()` again till the input char is not `\n` depending on whether we want to stop or skip.

Answer (score -1):

The next character can be read using `fgetc`. Since you cannot know in advance whether it is blank or not, you have to take the risk and read it. If it then turns out not to be non-blank, you can put it back using `fputc`.

Comment: OP *wants* the first non-whitespace character, not the last whitespace, so `ungetc` (which you meant to say, as opposed to `fputc` which is very wrong) is not needed.